# sums over partitions and sums with variable indices

Tags: summation

Is there neat way to implement following sums in mathematica?
$$s(l,k)=\sum\limits_{p_1+p_2+...+p_l=k} f_l(p_1,p_2,...,p_l) $$
and
$$t(l)=\sum\limits_{i_1,i_2,...,i_l=1}^n f_l(i_1,i_2,...,i_l)$$
Where $p_1,...,p_l\geq1$ ($p_1,...p_l\in\mathbb N$) and $l\in\mathbb N$ isn't fixed?

It seems I could use IntegerPartitions{k,{l}}, but this doesn't really seem neat! I'm also having trouble with implementing the 2nd sum, as $l$ is variable.

Comment: I think I can get it running with IntegerPartitions. Still I want to ask how to implement $t(l)$ in a nice way?

Comment: `FrobeniusSolve[]` may be more expedient than `IntegerPartitions[]` in your first sum, if only a little slower. For your second: `Sum[f @@ Array[K, l], ##] & @@ Transpose[PadRight[{Array[K, l]}, {2, Automatic}, n]]` is an obvious solution, but there might be more efficient ones, more so if your $f_l$ has symmetry of some sort.

Comment: Ok, I'll stick with IntegerPartitions for now, but I guess I can use FrobeniusSolve for more general sums! Thanks for the comment anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways of computing `t[l]`:

Using `Sum`:

```
Sum[ f @@ Table[i[j], {j, l}], ##] & @@ Table[{i[j], n}, {j, l}]
```

Generating all index lists:

```
Total[f @@@ Tuples[Range[n], l]]
```

Recursive:

```
rec[depth_] := If[depth == 0, f @@ Table[i[j], {j, l}], Sum[rec[depth - 1], {i[depth], n} ] ];
rec[l]
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I didn't know "Tuples"! I really like this one! Looks very clean to me! I think I'll use the second one, so I can setup my f[] very easy, so the argument can be a tuple!

Comment: Hey, I've got another question: I have multiple lists (t1,t2,t3,t4) and i want to make a new list such that it contains all elements of the form {a,b,c,d} where a,b,c,d are from t1,t2,t3,t4. I figured out I could use Flatten[Table[{t1[[i]], t2[[j]]}, {i, Length[t1]}, {j, Length[t2]}], 1] (here for 2 lists) but this doesn't seem very satisfiying! Is there a better way?

Comment: Use `Tuples` again! See the docs.

Comment: Haha thanks again! I guess all I needed was Tuples!!!